# Does Location.convert() yield values with comma as separator?

Tags: java, android, geolocation, substring, separator

My Android app deals with geo-location.

This is a code snippet from the source code:

```
...
String latDegrees = Location.convert(latitude, Location.FORMAT_DEGREES);
...
```

In my test it has

```
latitude 44.4929057
```

but

```
latDegrees "44,49291"
```

You see that the comma is used as separator, while it seems that the dot is the standard, for example in Gmaps urls, if I am not wrong.

In my app I have to perform much "substringing" so I have to be sure that the convert function yields the same format in all Locales.

So can I assume that the DD,DDDDD format (with comma separator) is safe to use for substringing in general? Or is my code wrong?

Comment: no its wrong when you parse it as double or int .it will be throw exception.

Comment: @Avinash The app parses the string itself, I just need to know whether that is the ultimate form the app will encounter in all Locales.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the separator character in the result from Location.convert method can be found in both forms dot='.' or comma=','

Maybe other forms exist according to locales.

It seems thar dot and comma are the most common, while some other decimal separators exist:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator

Furthermore some countries have other separators for groups of digits but here I am dealing with a particular method for converting location coordinates.